# React component props. How to get the inner object?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a classes object like this:

```
classes: {
    divBlock: "divBlockClass",
    rootBlock: "rootBlockClass"
}
```

How i can take divBlock property and pass to otherProps remaining classes object

```
const Component = ({height, className, classes /*i need to take a divBlock property*/, ...otherProps}) => {
    console.log(otherProps); //log props who are not pulled out
    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can spread `props` inside the function body.

```
const Component = (props) => {
  const {height, className, classes, ...restProps} = props;
  const { divBlock, ...restClassProps } = classes;
  const otherProps = {...restProps, classes: restClassProps };
  console.log(otherProps); //log props who are not pulled out
  return <div />
};
```

Comment: This help's. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
const Component = ({
    height,
    className,
    classes : { divBlock }, ...otherProps
}) => {
    console.log(otherProps);

    return (
        <div>

        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Nope it's haven't :) i tried like this, before asking this question :( in my console.log i don't see the classes object :(

Comment: What do you mean you're not getting classes object ?

Comment: yes, when it's declared like this `classes : { divBlock }` then otherProps not getting classes object

Comment: @SakhiMansoor Yes, and after that rest of the `classes` props the OP wants to forward ....

Comment: @Marty You can't do in one line, you need to arrange it in more than one line as I tried to show in my answer.

Comment: @SakhiMansoor yes, i want to divBlock, but remaining classes object still needed to pass it with otherProps in next component

Comment: Then you should not destruct  it. Just extract classes from it